# CSS Horizontal gap between divs

Tags: css

[image]

As you can see there is a gap between the first (yellow outlined) div and the second (red-outlined) div.  I've tried several things but nothing works so far.

```
#borderLeft{

    background: url(../01_templates/borderLeft.png) left no-repeat;
    display:inline;
    position relative;
    left:50px;
    float:left;
    width:133px;
    border:1px dotted yellow;

}

#border{

    background: url(../01_templates/borderCenter.png) left repeat-x;
    display:inline;
    position:inherit;
    width:100%;
    border:1px dotted red;
    margin-right:116px;

}

#borderRight{

    background: url(../01_templates/borderRight.png) left no-repeat;
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    border:1px dotted yellow;
    width:133px;

}


<div id="borderLeft"></div>
<div id="border"></div>
<div id="borderRight"></div>
```

Comment: why `float` while `position:absolute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP's original problem could be fixed by setting `font-size: 0` on the `div`s.

The following is a modern approach based on [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
}

.parent .double {
  border-color: red;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div class="double"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brunoscopelliti/yGvTC/ and try to toogle the class .p

Comment: Thank you Bruno, but the inner div must be scaled to the remaining width (100%).

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the `display: inline;` property. Inline elements are always displayed with white space between them that isn't part of their `padding` or `margin`.

If this is what's causing it, here are a few solutions. You can get rid of any white space between the elements in your code, like so:

```
<div id="borderLeft"></div><div id="border"></div><div id="borderRight"></div>
```

Or you could float them instead.

```
div { float: left; }
```

There might be other solutions, but typically I find myself avoiding `display: inline;` — particularly on structural elements, like divs — because of that white space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried this including the font-size recommendation below with no effect.